# Vba: Problem accessing sorted and doubly filtered column' s values

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on VBA and the task I need to carry out is firstly to sort the values of a column inside a sheet, then to filter for values inside another column, then to filter again inside another column and then to access elements inside the just filtered column.
I am doing the following:

Sorting:

```
   Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("H1:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

First filter:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A2:AB" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="variable1"
```

Second filter:

```
'Worksheets(1).Range("A2:AB" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _  "variable2", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Activating values:

```
'Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Activate
```

Accessing values:

```
For Each z In Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      'MsgBox (z.Value)
```

Doing the following, when activating the double filtered column, all the sheet get activated and not just the filtered column I am interested in. Whereas, if I remove:

```
   Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

from above, the accessing works properly, but I need this string of code otherwise the sorting is wrong.

What is going on ?

Comment: I don't think you need to redefine the range depth, so  `.Range("$C$1:$I$18").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"` and `.Range("$C$1:$I$18").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="x"`

Comment: You mean when filtering? I do so because the length of the columns in not fixed

Comment: Yes, even though the range looks shorter, as it's filtered, it still exists